# Get xml dom child element in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I have an XML document like this:

```
<section>
   <description></description>
   <question>
       <description></description>
   </question>
</section>
```

I have got the sectionXML stored in a variable called SectionXML. I use:

```
section.description = SectionXML.getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0];

section.description = section.description ? section.description.nodeValue : "";
```

However, `SectionXML.getElementsByTagName("description")` returns a list of many descriptions, as if we look many children deeper (great grand children etc) we can see they all have a description, but I just want to get the immediate child of SectionXML with the tag name of "description". How do I do that?

Comment: The code you have should do that, *getElementsByTagName* returns the elements in DOM order, so the "closest" child will be first.

Comment: @RobG The OP meant to be there nested description element...

Comment: @BhojendraNepal—so you mean "*I just want to get the immediate child…*" should have been "*…immediate child**ren**…*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use querySelectorAll():

```
SectionXML.querySelectorAll("section>description")[0]
// use > to get direct element only
```

Comment: Thanks, I got this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': '>description' is not a valid selector.`